# How to test the current version of GCC at compile time?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, versions

I would like to include a different file depending on the version of GCC. More precisely I want to write:

```
#if GCC_VERSION >= 4.2
#  include <unordered_map>
#  define EXT std
#elif GCC_VERSION >= 4
#  include <tr1/unordered_map>
#  define EXT std
#else
#  include <ext/hash_map>
#  define unordered_map __gnu_cxx::hash_map
#  define EXT __gnu_cxx
#endif
```

I don't care about gcc before 3.2.

I am pretty sure there is a variable defined at preprocessing time for that, I just can't find it again.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, after more searches, it one possible way of doing it is using `__GNUC_PREREQ` defined in `features.h`.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  include <features.h>
#  if __GNUC_PREREQ(4,0)
//      If  gcc_version >= 4.0
#  elif __GNUC_PREREQ(3,2)
//       If gcc_version >= 3.2
#  else
//       Else
#  endif
#else
//    If not gcc
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code fails with the clang compiler, which defines `__GNUC__`, but doesn't include `features.h`.

Comment: Well, this code is to know the version of GCC, so it's not surprising that it fails if clang partially impersonate GCC.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I was wrong. The `features.h` include is simply a Linux specific thing, and should not be relied on for any code that is intended to compile on other platforms.

Comment: This code has been tested on Mac OS X, Windows (MingW32 and MingW64) and Linux ... I am fairly sure features.h is a GCC specific include file.

Comment: The file is not directly from GCC, but rather from the glibc project.  Surely, you can't assume the existence of this file based on the current compiler.

Answer (score 61):

There are a number of macros that should be defined for your needs:

```
__GNUC__              // major
__GNUC_MINOR__        // minor
__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__   // patch
```

The version format is major.minor.patch, e.g. 4.0.2

The documentation for these can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html).

Answer (score 23):

As a side note:

To find all the predefined macros:

- Create empty file t.cpp
- `g++ -E -dM t.cpp`

Comment: Without creating an empty file: g++ -E -dM - </dev/null

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello: Your comment is only 7 years late.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello: Seems to have been edited just adding code quotes to the one line (and was approved).