# for each in GCC and GCC version

Tags: c++, gcc, foreach, c++11

how can I use for each loop in GCC?

and how can i get GCC version? (in code)

Comment: I don't see any relationship between the two questions...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a lambda, e.g.

```
// C++0x only.
std::for_each(theContainer.begin(), theContainer.end(), [](someType x) {
    // do stuff with x.
});
```

The [range-based for loop](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html) is supported by GCC since 4.6.

```
// C++0x only
for (auto x : theContainer) {
   // do stuff with x.
}
```

The ["for each" loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx) syntax is an MSVC extension. It is not available in other compilers.

```
// MSVC only
for each (auto x in theContainer) {
  // do stuff with x.
}
```

But you could just use [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/foreach.html). It is portable and available without C++0x too.

```
// Requires Boost
BOOST_FOREACH(someType x, theContainer) {
  // do stuff with x.
}
```

---

See [*How do I test the current version of GCC ?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259248/how-do-i-test-the-current-version-of-gcc) on how to get the GCC version.

Comment: no,
in C++0x format. like as VC++ 2010:


for each( auto it in vec)
{
cout << it << endl;
}

Comment: @user: `for each` is not C++0x.

Comment: Is `for each` C++cli, or is it an extension to raw C++?

Comment: @Johannes std::for_each(,,) is currently part of the ISO Standard C++, defined in 2003. It is not an extension, it is part of the currently available features in C++. One has to include the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: GCC 4.6 was [released](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/) with [range-based for](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html#cplusplus).

Comment: This answer should be fixed. GCC as of version 4.6 DOES support range-based for.

Answer (score 6):

there is also the traditionnal way, not using C++0X lambda. The `<algorithm>` header is designed to be used with objects that have a defined operator parenthesis. ( C++0x lambdas are only of subset of objects that have the operator () )

```
struct Functor
{
   void operator()(MyType& object)
   {
      // what you want to do on objects
   }
}

void Foo(std::vector<MyType>& vector)
{
  Functor functor;
  std::for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), functor);
}
```

see [algorithm header reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) for a list of all c++ standard functions that work with functors and lambdas.