# How to check the version of libpcap at compile time in my program

Tags: c, cmake, libpcap

I have a program that I want to use `pcap_create()` in, but before I use this API, I want to ensure this API exists. I know in version 1.0 of `libpcap` this API exists, but how can I check the version of `libpcap` at compile time?

For example, I want something like the below:

```
#if PCAP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 1
pcap_create(...
#else
pcap_open_live(...
#endif
```

Comment: Linux? - [Perhaps this will help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58846/viewing-linux-library-executable-version-info)

Comment: @Rykker, does hat answer imply the linker will complain when the version of the library is not as required in the C source file? Or is a run-time check against this `NEEDED` necessary?

Comment: "ITNOA" - what does this mean?

Comment: @ryyker I want to cross platform approach, and I want to use my approach programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually care about the library *version*, you care about whether or not the symbol `pcap_create` is present. Therefore, this is a job for [`CheckSymbolExists`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckSymbolExists.html):

```makefile
# This assumes PCAP_INCLUDE_DIRS is appropriately set somehow, maybe via:
#
#     find_path(PCAP_INCLUDE_DIRS "pcap/pcap.h")
#
# or something else in your CMakeLists.txt

include(CheckSymbolExists)

set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "${PCAP_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
check_symbol_exists(pcap_create "pcap/pcap.h" HAVE_PCAP_CREATE)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE "HAVE_PCAP_CREATE=$<BOOL:${HAVE_PCAP_CREATE}>")
```

This will define `HAVE_PCAP_CREATE` in `main.cpp` to `1` or `0` if the `pcap_create` function exists or not. Then in your code you would write:

```
#if HAVE_PCAP_CREATE
pcap_create(...);
#else
pcap_open_live(...);
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, so Did you say libpcap does not provide any pre-compile  version macro something like [__GNUC_PREREQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/259279/1539100)? or you just say, the best way (best practice) to check API exist in the third party library, is checking symbol?